# flatMap and flatMap single for groupped observables

Tags: rx-java, rx-java3

I am new in RxJava and trying to understand it. I have the following source:

```
Observable<Employee> obs = Observable.just(
    new Employee(101, "Jim", 68_000, 4.2),
    new Employee(123, "Bill", 194_000, 6.7));  

obs.groupBy(e -> e.getRating())
   .flatMapSingle(e -> e.toMultimap(key -> e.getKey(), emp -> emp.getName()))
   .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

This approach prints the keys and the associated value.
If I do:

```
obs.groupBy(e -> e.getRating())
       .flatMapSingle(e -> e.toList())
       .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

It seems to print the list of values associated with the key.
But how does `flatMapSingle` exactly work? What is the difference with `flatMap`?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

```
Maps each element of the upstream {@code Flowable} into {@link SingleSource}s, subscribes to all of them
     * and merges their {@code onSuccess} values, in no particular order, into a single {@code Flowable} sequence.
```

It works in the same way in both cases.
when your invoke

```
flatMapSingle(e -> { // convert to some value})
```

you convert "e" to the value returned  by the lambda.
in your case "e" is `GroupedFlowable`.

in first case you convert all the elements to map, which contains entries(key, value), in the second case you convert it to the list.
`flatMapSingle()` method works in the same way in both cases.

You have different results because you use different implementation of `Function` that you put to `flatMapSingle` as a parameter.

`Function` parameter which in you case looks like `e -> { .... }` determines the way how to handle elements that was emirted by the source.